# how to substitute, find and replace in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, substitution

I have some data in table 1.0 in the following format; Name, X, Y, Z 
Where name is text, X,Y,Z - number

Table 2.0 data is in the same format and text column matches (same name) the one in table 1.0.

Table 3.0 is in the following format X, Y, Z (numbers)
Table 3.0 contains, should contain formulas from the outputs from table 1.0 and 2.0

Question: What formula to use in table 3 so it

1. In table3.0: Searches for specific name in table1.0 that is also used in table 2.0
2. In table 3.0: substract data (X, Y, Z) from table 2.0 & 1.0

I'm attaching a picture of the tables

[image: TABLES]

Updated table with names also in table 3.0[Table_updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8Jnq.jpg)

p.s. Table 1 and 2 have same names, pictures attached only show arbitrary data.

Help much appreciated as I have run out of ideas how to approach it!

Thanks!

[results should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0NuV.jpg)

Comment: Could a vlookup formula work if you table 3.0 also has the name to bring data from the other tables?

Comment: I can surely add name to table 3.0.  if that will help with formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this one should work for you:

```
=C32-VLOOKUP($B32,$B$11:$E$27,COLUMN()-5,0)
```

Put in `G32` and drag right and down.

Comment: Thank you for that. I copied the formula but the result is still wrong. I have attached a picture showing what the result should be.

Comment: Simply speaking. I need to substract values from table 1 and 2 and for it to appear in table3.

Comment: @Damio I did a small mistake. Check it again.

Comment: So I don't have to go to each individual cell in table 3 and move the formula cells to the correct ones. ( I have a lot of data!)

Comment: @Damio, please check the answer as solved by clicking the grey tick mark below the voting buttons. It shows other people that the question is solved and give both of you some credit points :). And welcome to Stackoverflow! =)

Comment: Just one more question please! How can I look up 2 tables?

Comment: Is it possible for the formula to only search for the first 4 characters? for example I have data RO01 in table 1.0 and RO01chk in table 2.0

Comment: Also, Can you explain the formula please? I like to know what I'm doing :)

Comment: @Damio You can read more about `VLOOKUP` [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1). I made it a little more dynamic by using `COLUMN()` in third argument, so you can drag it without changing this value manually.

Comment: For your second question, you can try using `LEFT($B32,4)`, but I'm not sure if this works.
I don't understand what do you mean by "How can I look up 2 tables". It's best if you post a new question for this one.

Comment: Thanks for the link and help.

Comment: Everything smooth :). I just don't understand the "COLUMN()-5,0" statement

Comment: @Damio Third argument of `VLOOKUP` is the number of column from range send in second argument from which you want to get a value. `COLUMN()` returns the number of the column where it's typed. I had to subtract 5 to get a proper value. `0` at the end is the fourth argument, which force the formula to look for exact match only (it's the same as `FALSE`).

Comment: All understood now. Thank you.